# How do I search for a piece of text in a text file, and then print out the whole line of text containing the piece I was searching for in ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

This would be used in a search engine esc. manor, so that you can serch a text file and print out everything that is on its line, I.E.

```
File:
Ruby Is an Awesome programming language! 

Query: Ruby
What is returned: Ruby Is an Awesome programming language!
```

How I do it, is beyond me. So does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please, show a *minimal* example of the *exact* code you have trouble with, and any and all error messages and warnings you are getting.

Comment: When searching for a piece of text, is the text contained in a string, a file, or what?  And "answer with all of them" doesn't cut it here.  Be specific about what you want, because you can only choose one answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example assumes the text is entered in a string with carriage returns as line breaks.

```
def search(string, query)
    string = string.split("\n"); 
    string.each do |line|
        if line.include?(query)
            return line
        end 
    end 
end
```

You would call the method as follows:

```
test_string = "Hello, I'm a test string. \n Did you know that Ruby is pretty cool? \n Of course I did!"
search(test_string, "Did you")
```

**EDIT**

In the case that the string is found more than once, this will return all instances:

```
def search(string, query)
    string.split("\n").select{ |line| line.include?(query)}
end
```